# Continuously reading piped bytes from a file

Tags: c++, linux, unix, pipe

I have the following code to pipe bytes from a file in to my C++ application:

```
  char *buffer = new char[SIZE];

  while (!std::cin.eof()) {
      std::cin.read(buffer, SIZE);
      for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        std::cout << buffer[i] << std::endl;
      }
  }
```

However, the problem is I am only outputting/reading the first SIZE bytes of the pipe. How can I read all of the bytes from a pipe where the pipe size is greater than SIZE?

Comment: Please read istream doc. You should check the return value!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/

Seems to suggest what I have done is ok? :s

Comment: No. You have not. Read method could reach EOF before reading requested size.

Comment: Yes? If I had a stream size of 45 bytes and I read 10 bytes at a time the last read would have EOF in the middle?

Comment: Yes and [read operation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) will only partially fill the buffer.

Comment: On the last read- yes? Because there is only 5 bytes on the last grab?  I don't see why this is a problem? My problem is that I know I have say 40 bytes and only the first grab of 10 bytes is working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48008/discussion-between-basilevs-and-user997112)

Comment: Chat discussion indicates that the problem for resolved for OP somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcount() is not checked after the read operation.
Proper way:

```
while (!std::cin.eof()) {
      std::cin.read(buffer, SIZE);
      for(int i=0; i<cin.gcount(); i++){
        std::cout << buffer[i] << std::endl;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I will just note that if you have a byte stream one may want to remove std::endline to avoid making a new line. I tried to pipe the content of a GRIB file and just write it to another file. That only works if I don't create a new line using endl;